# How to split String column right justified into multiple columns in R?

Tags: r, tidyverse, data-wrangling, tidy

I have a dataset contains a column like this:

```
dput(df[1:20, 8]) %>% structure()

 [1] "TASBUDAK-EREGLI (KONYA)"           
 [2] "HANCAGIZ-SAMANDAG (HATAY)"         
 [3] "SOGUT-DOGANSEHIR (MALATYA)"        
 [4] "KUCUKLU-DOGANSEHIR (MALATYA)"      
 [5] "KEMALPASA-GOKSUN (KAHRAMANMARAS)"  
 [6] "ULUKOY-(MALATYA)"                  
 [7] "KAZANLIPINAR-(KAHRAMANMARAS)"      
 [8] "ULUBAHCE-PAZARCIK (KAHRAMANMARAS)" 
 [9] "EMIRLER-NURDAGI (GAZIANTEP)"       
[10] "CELIKKOY-GOLBASI (ADIYAMAN)"       
[11] "KAZANDERE-GOKSUN (KAHRAMANMARAS)"  
[12] "BESCI-EMIRGAZI (KONYA)"            
[13] "ORDEKDEDE-PAZARCIK (KAHRAMANMARAS)"
[14] "CAVUSLU-DOGANSEHIR (MALATYA)"      
[15] "KULLAR-NURHAK (KAHRAMANMARAS)"     
[16] "IZCI-SURUC (SANLIURFA)"            
[17] "YAZIKOY-AFSIN (KAHRAMANMARAS)"     
[18] "DEMIRCI-EMIRGAZI (KONYA)"          
[19] "ORTULU-LICE (DIYARBAKIR)"          
[20] "KAMISTAS-(MALATYA)"
```

I want to separate this column into three columns with the code below:

```
df %>% 
  separate(Region, 
           into = c("Suburb", "Town", "City"))
```

and the result is that:

| Suburb | Town | City |
| --- | --- | --- |
| KAZANDERE | GÖKSUN | KAHRAMANMARAS |
| DOGU AKDENIZ | NA | NA |
| ISIKLI | YESILYURT | MALATYA |
| COBANTASI | BINGOL | NA |
| GOKSUN | KAHRAMANMARAS | NA |
| YAGMURLU | GOKSUN | KAHRAMANMARAS |

But i want to split this columns with a right justified order like that:

| Suburb | Town | City |
| --- | --- | --- |
| KAZANDERE | GÖKSUN | KAHRAMANMARAS |
| NA | NA | DOGU AKDENIZ |
| ISIKLI | YESILYURT | MALATYA |
| NA | COBANTASI | BINGOL |
| NA | GOKSUN | KAHRAMANMARAS |
| YAGMURLU | GOKSUN | KAHRAMANMARAS |

How can I do that?

Comment: Can you share your sample dataset using `dput()` function

Comment: i put the sample of my dataset into the post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
df %>% 
  separate(Region, into = c("Suburb", "Town", "City"), fill = 'left')
```

should do the trick

Comment: it doesn't work for me. I also tried `fill = right`. This also does not work.

Comment: @AliOsman first the code you provided itself does not produce what you have on my end. I thought i had an issue with data so just extended your code. `fill = 'right'` should pad NA's to the right of the string ie beginning of string. So if your code above works, then the fill right should definitely work. First how is your code producing `DOGU AKDENIZ, NA,NA` is the second row? That does not seem correct